# golang docker client build failed : 401 Unauthorized

Tags: docker, go, unauthorized, harbor

```
        cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.WithVersion("1.40"))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer cli.Close()

    authConfig := types.AuthConfig{
        Username: "xxx",
        Password: "xxx",
    }

    buildCtx, _ := archive.TarWithOptions("./", &archive.TarOptions{
        ExcludePatterns: []string{".git"},
    })

    plain := "plain"
    buildOpts := types.ImageBuildOptions{
        Version: types.BuilderBuildKit,
        Tags:    []string{image},
        BuildArgs: map[string]*string{
            "progress": &plain,
        },
        AuthConfigs: map[string]types.AuthConfig{
            f.CONFIG.HARBOR.Url: authConfig,
        },
    }

    ctxWithTimeout, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), time.Second*1800)
    buildResponse, err := cli.ImageBuild(ctxWithTimeout, buildCtx, buildOpts)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
```

hi,these code work well on Harbor API 1.9.0
but it cant work on Harbor API 2.0
i have read https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/auth/token/ but still cant solve this problem
look for some help
thx

btw the username and password is correct

Comment: failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: unexpected status code http://xxx/v2/docker/dockerfile/manifests/1.4: 401 Unauthorized